# Django: Sending email from user logged in

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-email

I have been reading on how to set up email in django. I want to have a page where I input a user's email, subject and message and the email gets delivered. The email should be from the user who has logged in. Is it possible to achieve this in Django?

Please note that the system has multiple users. So the email shall be delivered from the logged in user

Comment: **Nope**, unless you own the domain of their email, OR you have the appropriate SPF or DKIM records.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat what do you mean by own the domain of their email?

Comment: Suppose their email is `abc@example.com` the domain here is `example.com` and owning it means you own the DNS record for `example.com`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, ohh okay... :(

Comment: Otherwiseit will be a spam